# How Can I Create a Button That Open Link From A Multiple URL List?

Tags: javascript, button, hyperlink

I want to create a button which can open link from the URL list serial wise. So, I have like 3 links that I want to connect to the button.

so here's an example what I am exactly looking for:

Visitor 1 comes to the website and clicks on the button, the visitor will be redirected to the **URL1** from the list.

Visitor 2 arrives to the website and clicks on the button, the visitor will be redirected to the **URL2** from the list.

Visitor 3 arrives to the website and clicks on the button, the visitor will be redirected to the **URL3** from the list.

!--process repeats--!

Visitor 4 arrives to the website and clicks on the button, the visitor will be redirected to the **URL1** from the list.

Visitor 5 arrives to the website and clicks on the button, the visitor will be redirected to the **URL2** from the list.

Visitor 6 arrives to the website and clicks on the button, the visitor will be redirected to the **URL3** from the list.

Let me know how can I make this possible; I know about RANDOM URL list thing but I don't want that. I don't want random links to be opened rather I want the links to be opened in a serial form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Store the user count in your server and check it every time someone clicks on a link.

Comment: If you have any code that you've attempted this with, it is useful to include it so others can give a more applicable solution to what you already have.